# How to find the maximum across all groups when there can be multiple maximum values in one group

Tags: sql

Question  : Name the most powerful heroes of each race.

Table:

```
Hero Race Power
a-bomb human 7000
amazo human 7000
ajax cyborg 5000
mephis cyborg 5600
ammo human 1000
ardina alien 2000
jagua alien 200
myntria alien 2300
hyspace alien 2300
...
...
...
```

and so on.

Now for this data, for the race "human", we have a-bomb and amazo both of whom have the highest power. So my output should include both their names.

My expected output:

```
Race Hero
human a-bomb
human amazo
cyborg memphis
alien myntria
alien hyspace
```

Please help.

I tried grouping by race and selecting the max, but that just gives one maximum when the same race has multiple maximum.

```
SELECT race,hero, max(Power)
FROM heroes_info
GROUP BY race;
```

My expected output:

```
Race Hero
human a-bomb
human amazo
cyborg memphis
alien myntria
alien hyspace
```

My actual output:

```
Race Hero
human a-bomb
cyborg memphis
alien myntria
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use the rank function to sort the heroes based on power desc and print the heros with rank 1 as below

```
SELECT race, 
       hero 
FROM   (SELECT hero, 
               race, 
               Rank() 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY race 
                   ORDER BY power DESC) rank1 
        FROM   heroes_info) AS heroes 
WHERE  heroes.rank1 = 1
```

Comment: Please mark this as answer if this helps to resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT race,hero, Power
FROM heroes_info a
where power in (select max(pawer) from heroes_info a1 where a.race=a1.race)
```